# How to bring a specific overlayed image to the foreground

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I prepared a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/u177yr8z/2/) to explain my problem.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- I am making a grid out of four transparent square PNGs that float left
- each PNG is clickable as a label for a checkbox
- when a box is clicked the opacity of the PNG should change to show it's active
- grid layer should be on top of a "background image"
- "background image" is loaded dynamically so it cannot use CSS
- "background image" is a separate `div` with `position:absolute`
- user clicks on a given square of the grid
- user submits form that contains checkbox info (from clicked boxes)

My problem:

- without the "background image" the script works as expected
- with the "background image" it stays in the foreground and when I click it activates the image itself, making it semi-transparent

My question:

- how do I bring the PNG squares to the foreground so they are clickable and change in opacity, the user having no interaction with the "background image"?

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>
      <label for="R0_C0">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwTE.png">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="R0_C0" value="1" class="hidden_checkbox" id="R0_C1">
  </span>
  <span>
      <label for="R0_C1">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwTE.png">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="R0_C1" value="1" class="hidden_checkbox" id="R0_C1">
  </span>
  <span>
      <label for="R1_C0">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwTE.png">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="R1_C0" value="1" class="hidden_checkbox" id="R1_C0">
  </span>
  <span>
      <label for="R1_C1">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWwTE.png">
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="R1_C1" value="1" class="hidden_checkbox" id="R1_C1">
  </span>
</div>

<!-- comment/remove code below this line to see the expected behavior -->

<div class="bg_img">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bVu3.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 64px
}

span {
  float: left
}

.hidden_checkbox {
  display: none
}

.selected_checkbox {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.bg_img {
  position:absolute
}
```

JS

```
  $(function() {
    $('img').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected_checkbox');
    });
  });
```

Comment: perhaps an explanation on the reason for the down vote would allow me to improve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `z-index` to help specify that you want your image to be in the background like so:

```
.bg_img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u177yr8z/3/ 
More information on z-order/z-index: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 0):

Improving your selectors would help. Even using "label > img" would prevent the background image from being roped into click events.

Basically any css selector argument is valid to use with jQuery, so just be more specific when you tell it what you're listening for.

Comment: `label > img` or `label img` don't seem to work, no change when clicking